# Can tyres placed on track derail trains?

Tags: rail

This question is based on the following [news article](https://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Tiruchirapalli/express-train-hits-lorry-tyre-placed-on-track-near-tiruchi-suffers-detention/article66924462.ece). I just want to know if rubber tyres are strong enough to cause rail derailment if placed on the track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by “tire” they mean “wheel & tire” then it might act as a tamp so yes possible.

Or, as they state it can break pipes and halt the train.

Anything on the tracks could cause enough issues to damage or derail a train. Just depends on many factors: mass, angle of impact etc

Answer (score 1):

The tires did not derail the train. More generally if they could then why do saboteurs waste time with explosives and so on?

Comment: I just wanted to know if 'tyres' do have potential to derail trains. By Lord's grace it did not happen.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what you asked and my second sentence indicated a probable answer. If easily obtainable tires could derail trans then saboteurs would use them rather than hard to obtain explosives.